# TYPO3 remove "copy 1" text

Tags: typo3

I use TYPO3 version 8.7.10. I am trying to remove "copy 1" text when I copy the content.

I have tried:

```
TCEMAIN.table.pages {
    disablePrependAtCopy = 1
    disableHideAtCopy = 1
}

TCEMAIN.table.tt_content {
    disablePrependAtCopy = 1
    disableHideAtCopy = 1
}
```

Not successfully

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you enter those values to Typoscript-Setup or the Page TSConfig of the Root Page? It belongs to the TSConfig in the page configuration.

Comment: Should I add it somewhere here ? https://prnt.sc/jcnpc9 I added it to the file root.ts

Comment: Its wrong there. It belongs to the page configuration. Right click your root page -> Edit -> Tab "Resources" -> Page TSConfig. There it belongs to.

Comment: I made it so https://prnt.sc/jcnupm , but "kopie" text still appear (( https://prnt.sc/jcnvid

Comment: Just re-tested the solution as proposed by Paul, it works. For more information on TSconfig and possible overrides that may be active in your case, check the official documentation at https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TSconfigReference/